# Show that if $ G $ is a graph with $ n $ vertices such that $ | E (G) | > \frac {n^2}{4} $ then $ G $ contains a triangle.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Show that if $ G $ is a graph with $ n $ vertices such that $ | E (G) | > \frac {n^2}{4} $ then $ G $ contains a triangle.

My try:

Suppose $ G $ does not contain any triangle, then there is no clique of size $ k \geq 3 $. By the Turán theorem $$  | E (G) | \leq \left(1- \frac{1}{3-1} \right) \frac{n^2}{2}= \frac{n^2}{4} $$
Therefore, if $ G $ is a graph with $ n $ vertices such that $ | E (G) | > \frac {n^2}{4} $ then $ G $ contains a triangle.

Comment: Suggestions for what? Your proof looks fine to me (besides you mean *no clique of size $\geq 3$* don’t you?)

Comment: I am guessing tat the point of this exercise is to not invoke Turan's theorem and give a self-contained proof.

Comment: I got the same feeling. Because seems to easy with the Turan´s theorem.

Comment: There are certainly elementary proofs of this fact that do not appeal to Turán's theorem. For instance, if $G$ is a graph with more than $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges, then $G$ contains a vertex whose deletion leaves a graph with more than $\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}$ edges (this is proven by simple counting and considering even/odd cases). Using this fact, the proof of your statement would follow by induction immediately.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629542/every-graph-with-n-ge3-vertices-and-more-than-fracn24-edges-contains-a).